# javascript not rendering on cloud server in rails4 app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4, digital-ocean

This is my custom layout file:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'template/template', media: 'all', "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'template/template', "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

and the below is my `template.js` file:

```
//= require jquery.min
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require bootstrap.min
//= require gmap3.min
//= require jquery.appear
//= require jquery.bxslider.min
//= require turbolinks
```

I have made required changes in `production.rb` file, `assets.rb` and `application` file but the javascripts are not rendering on the production server.
I am getting the path of the my javascript file locally but on production server its showing Not Found.

What did I miss?

Comment: _i have made below changes also_ : `config.assets.compile = true
config.assets.precompile =  ['*.js', '*.css', '*.css.erb']`

Comment: **And after i ran**  `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile`

Comment: after you've run the assets:precompile command, do you see all the files you require in the public/assets folder?

Comment: yes i have seen all the compiled css, and i checked out on my digital ocean server, there all the assets are compiled.

Comment: Hmm ok so can you try opening a file from the public assets folder in your browser? Might be a nginx or Apache config issue?